# Error when post data to serve express using hash bcrypt to hash password

Tags: javascript, api, express, sequelize.js, bcrypt

I try to write a Api using express and sequelize. I'm writing *create user* function and use **bcrypt** to hash password.

```
 const createNewUser = (data) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let check = await checkUserEmail(data.email)
      if (check === true) {
        resolve({
          errcode: 1,
          errMessage: 'Your email is already exist!',
        })
      }
      let hashPassWordFromBcrypt = await hashUserPassWord(data.passWord)
  

      await db.User.create({
        email: data.email,
        passWord: hashPassWordFromBcrypt,
        firstName: data.firstName,
        lastName: data.lastName,
        address: data.address,
        phoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
        gender: data.gender === '1' ? true : false,
        roleId: data.roleId,
      })
     resolve({
       errcode: 0,
       errMessage: 'OK',
     })
} catch (error) {
  reject(error)
}
```

})
}

```
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)

const hashUserPassWord = (password) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let hashPassWord = await bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
      resolve(hashPassWord)
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error)
    }
  })
}

const checkUserEmail = (email) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const user = await db.User.findOne({ where: { email } })
      if (user) {
        resolve(true)
      }
      resolve(false)
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e)
    }
  })
}
```

I use **postman** to test. The problem is when I send data with a **email already exist**.The response: `errCode: 1` and `errMasege: Your email is already exist` but a **new user** created with same **email**.
But if I post a request with a **already exist email** and without **passWord**, **no new User** created.
Help me. Thanks.

Comment: is your question about bcrypt or the email already exists error?

Comment: btw putting async on a promise callback is bad practice, in your case you could make the function async and remove the new Promise wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `resolve` or `reject` statement does not exit the promise executor function. You should write

```js
if (check === true) {
  return resolve({
    errcode: 1,
    errMessage: 'Your email is already exist!',
  })
}
```

otherwise the `db.User.create` operation will be carried out afterwards.

(Your code

```js
if (user) {
  resolve(true)
}
resolve(false)
```

also seems to assume that `resolve` exits the executor function. But in this particular case, it does not matter, because `resolve(false)` has no effect if the promise has already resolved to `true`.)

Comment: Oh that work. Thanks. But I have another question.If resolve doesn't exit Promise, why I post a request with no passWord (with an already exist email), my app doesn't crash. It will crash if I post a data without passWord (new email). I have not validate data yet.

Comment: Without a `passWord`, `await hashUserPassWord(data.passWord)` is rejected, and the rejection is caught by the `catch (error)` block, so that `db.User.create` is not executed.